# Cannot bind data to dataset when searching from dataset C#?

Tags: ado.net, dataset

I have loaded data from the database to the dataset named **myDS**. **myDS** contains several tables. Then I bound one of those tables (named **Inventory**) into the datagridview named **dataGridViewInventory** and everything worked fine.
However, when I tried to search in the Inventory table and the result bound to the datagridview dataGridViewInventory but it appeared empty.

Here is the code of searching and binding:

```
 DataRow[] filteredRows =
                        myDS.Tables["Inventory"].Select(string.Format("Make LIKE '%{0}%'", txtMake.Text.Trim()));

            DataSet tempTaskDS = new DataSet("tempCars");

            //tempTaskDS.Tables.Add("TempInv");

            DataTable DataTable2 = new DataTable("TempInv");
            // This makes the new DataTable have the same columns as the existing DataTable.
            DataTable2 = myDS.Tables["Inventory"].Clone(); 

            foreach (DataRow r in filteredRows)
            {
                DataTable2.ImportRow(r);
            }
            tempTaskDS.Tables.Add(DataTable2);

            dataGridViewInventory.DataSource = tempTaskDS.Tables["TempInv"];
```

Can anyone tell me what I have gone wrong, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:
DO not need to use a temporary dataset, just use the BindingSource and bind the datatable to it, then bind the BindingSource to the datagridview. The code is below:

```
DataRow[] filteredRows =
                        myDS.Tables["Inventory"].Select(string.Format("Make LIKE '%{0}%'", txtMake.Text.Trim()));

            DataTable DataTable2 = new DataTable("TempInv");
            // This makes the new DataTable have the same columns as the existing DataTable.
            DataTable2 = myDS.Tables["Inventory"].Clone(); 

            foreach (DataRow r in filteredRows)
            {
                DataTable2.ImportRow(r);
            }

            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            bSource.DataSource = DataTable2;

            dataGridViewInventory.DataSource = bSource;
```